# What's the recommended way to stop the current version of app engine using gcloud?

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

I want to automatically start/stop our app engine services by running a bash script.

I know it's easy to run `gcloud app versions start/stop`, but I don't want to manually check the version number. I want to dynamically pass the version that is serving 100% traffic to gcloud and tell it to stop.

On the flip side, I also want to tell gcloud to start the most recently deployed version.

What's the recommended way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Note that the `gcloud app versions start|stop` commands are only applicable to manually scaled services, while traffic switching/splitting applies to dynamically scaled services.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to do that is to use `gcloud`'s keys and flags: [`projections`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/projections), [`--format`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/formats), [`--filters`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/filters). To read more directly from the terminal use [`gcloud topic`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/), for example:

```
gcloud topic projections
```

In order to see what fields/properties are available use `--format=flattened`, like:

```
gcloud app services list --format=flattened
```

For the sake of simplicity I will leave outside everything but `gcloud`.

```
for SERVICE in $(gcloud app services list --format='table[no-heading](id)'); do
    echo "for service $SERVICE :"

    RECENT=$(gcloud app versions list --format='table[no-heading](id)' --filter="service=$SERVICE" | tail -n1)

    echo 'y' | gcloud app versions start $RECENT

    VERSIONS=$(gcloud app versions list --format='table[no-heading](id)' --filter="service=$SERVICE AND version.servingStatus=SERVING AND NOT id=$RECENT" | tr '\n' ' ')

    echo 'y' | gcloud app versions stop $VERSIONS
done
```

`'table[no-heading](service)'` outputs a table without heading, which is set in brackets,  and a single column with service IDs, which is set in parentheses.

`--filter="service=$SERVICE AND version.servingStatus=SERVING AND NOT id=$RECENT"` will only show versions from indicated service that are serving, except the one indicated by `RECENT`.

Additionally, if you would want to use dates for filtering:

```
gcloud app versions list --format='table(id, version.servingStatus, version.createTime.date(format="%s"))' --filter="service=default" --sort-by="~version.createTime"
```

`version.createTime.date(format="%s")` is a [function date](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/projections#date) converting `version.createTime.date` into the number of seconds since the Epoch.

`%s` comes from [strftime(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html) and returns dates in Epoch format which is easier to understand and compare.

`--sort-by="~version.createTime"`sorts by creation date and because of `~` in descending order.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use the `--stop-previous-version` and/or `--promote` options when deploying with [`gcloud app deploy`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy) (they *should* be the default if I interpret the docs correctly, unless you use `--no-stop-previous-version` and/or `--no-promote`):

> `--promote`
>
> Promote the deployed version to receive all traffic. Overrides the
>   default `app/promote_by_default` property value for this command
>   invocation. Use `--no-promote` to disable.
>
> `--stop-previous-version`
>
> Stop the previously running version when deploying a new version that
>   receives all traffic. Overrides the default
>   `app/stop_previous_version` property value for this command
>   invocation. Use `--no-stop-previous-version` to disable.

But, if you're using the standard environment and dynamic scaling, you should be aware that if the previous version handles a lot of traffic there may be service degradation/interruptions during the switch (it may take a while for the GAE autoscaler to determine how many new version instances it needs to spin up to handle that traffic, see [Use traffic migration or splitting when switching to a new default version](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/scalability#switching_default_version). You can perform these programmatically, see  Not applicable to the flex environment, which doesn't support traffic splitting.

Also potentially of interest: [GAE shutdown or restart all the active instances of a service/app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45332283/gae-shutdown-or-restart-all-the-active-instances-of-a-service-app/45335739#45335739)

You can only control at which deployed version(s) is the traffic routed to by default, you can't really *stop* all traffic to a deployed version, it can always be reached via [targeted routing](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-requests-are-routed#targeted_routing).

BTW, the **gcloud app versions [[start](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/versions/stop)|[stop](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/versions/stop)]** commands are only applicable to manually scaled services:

> It may only be used if the scaling module for your service has been
>   set to manual.

Comment: Thanks Dan! However, I don't want to deploy a new version. I want to turn off/on an existing service, and I think those commands are only available using `gcloud app deploy`

Comment: I _do_ want to deploy and switch to a new version, but the `--stop-previous-version` flag explicitly states that it does not work for automatically scaled versions.  It's very annoying because, as far as I can tell, app engine _never_ turns off my auto scaled instances, even though they're receiving no traffic; presumably I could set the minimum instances to allow scaling to zero, but I don't want that for the _current_ version (I want a couple of instances live).