# How to provide a default error page if Flask app is not available in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, flask, gcloud

How to provide a default error page if Flask app is not available in Google App Engine. I see the following error if the app is not available and when its being deployed, how do I provide a more user friendly message.

Error: Not Found
The requested URL / was not found on this server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't: if the application is not available neither is its config, where custom error pages would be configured.

To avoid such errors it's better to always deploy a new app version and gradually switch traffic to it after it's verified to be working.

Related:

- [Continuous integration/deployment/delivery on Google App Engine, too risky?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40192557/continuous-integration-deployment-delivery-on-google-app-engine-too-risky/40193364#40193364)
- [What's the recommended way to stop the current version of app engine using gcloud?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48964843/whats-the-recommended-way-to-stop-the-current-version-of-app-engine-using-gclou/48971227#48971227)