# How to deploy python and node js at same time at same domain in google app engine?

Tags: python, node.js, express, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have a web application that I want to deploy it in Google cloud. It built with python and node js which node js communicates with python. How can I deploy the app with two different runtime ?
The node js `.yaml`:

```
runtime: nodejs
api_version: 1
env: flex
```

python `.yaml`

```
runtime: python
env: flex
threadsafe: true
runtime_config:
  python_version: 3
health_check:
   enable_health_check: True
   check_interval_sec: 5
   timeout_sec: 4
   unhealthy_threshold: 2
   healthy_threshold: 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have the code deployed as 2 separate services inside the same app, with total code isolation (any mix of language and standard/flex environments). See somehow related [Advantages of implementing CI/CD environments at GAE project/app level vs service/module level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43218971/advantages-of-implementing-ci-cd-environments-at-gae-project-app-level-vs-servic)

Watch out for the app-level configurations which are shared by all services (dispatch, cron, queue, datastore indexes).

The services are still deployed independently. Since the actual deployment time can take some longer time for the flex environment, you may find it difficult to time the 2 deployments to meet the `at the same time` requirement. But that can be improved by always deploying new versions and only *after* deployments switch the traffic to the new versions. Traffic switching is much faster than deployment and can be automated. See related [GAE shutdown or restart all the active instances of a service/app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45332283/gae-shutdown-or-restart-all-the-active-instances-of-a-service-app/45335739#45335739)